# comparing javascript objects using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have a master product list that has a logical object structure:

```
var myProducts = {
     "productInfo":{
        "productVariations":[{
            "ID":XXXXXXX,
            "Attributes":{
                "edition":'professional',
                "license":"perpetual"
            }
        },
        {
            "ID":XXXXXX,
            "Attributes":{
                "edition":'standard',
                "license":"perpetual"
            }
        },
        .
        .
        .
```

I am trying to compare this to a dynamically generated object array created by a product configurator application I have built. This list looks like this once generated:

```
var zcs_edition = [{ edition="standard", license="perpetual"}, { edition="professional", license="perpetual" }]
```

using $.inArray to compare the elements like below doesnt seem to be effective:

```
$.each(myProducts.productInfo.productVariations,function(i, val){
//console.log(this.productID);
    //console.log(val.productAttributes  );
    //console.log($.inArray(val.productAttributes, zcs_edition ))
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here, I half expected this to work.

Comment: In case you are willing to use underscore.js you could use its `_.isEqual` method. Works fine. See: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEqual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off there are two errors in you example: In your master product list you have the element `Attributes`, but in your code you are referring to it as `productAttribute`, and in your list `zcs_edition` you are using `=` instead of `:`.

To your problem: You can't compare objects like that in JavaScript. `{a: 1, b: 2} == {a: 1, b: 2}` will always return false, because they are two different object, even it the happen to have the same properties and property values.

You'd need to use a function that iterates over the properties and compares them one by one. See for example: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

This however means you can't use `$.inArray`, because it can't use a such a function. You'd have to iterate of the array yourself, too.

Comment: I should have picked that up.

Answer (score 0):

```
var zcs_edition = [{ edition="standard", license="perpetual"}, { edition="professional", license="perpetual" }]
```

`{ edition="standard", license="perpetual"}` is not a valid Object

it should be `{ edition:"standard", license:"perpetual"}`